# How can I find out how far away I am from adding a bounty on a question?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I see a question, and I think I should be able to add a bounty, but the button is not there.  How can I quickly figure out:

1. why it's not there?
2. if it's because of time, how far away am I from being able to add a bounty to a question?

Comment: @random - can you show me in this "duplicate" where my questions are answers as i dont see it . .

Comment: Do you have another bounty running? Does the mysterious question already have one? How old is this question that dare not speak its name?